# Windows Vista Factory Image Restore is giving error and computer keeps rebooting

Tags: boot, windows-vista

Hello I am attempting to restore my windows vista desktop and I do not have the CDs so I am using this Dell Factory Image Restore and this is the error I get and wondering is there anything I can do to restore this without having to buy a new Vista CD.

Problem Event Name:  StartupRepairV2
Problem Signature 01:  AutoFailover
Problem Signature 02:  6.0.6000.16386.0.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:  0
Problem Signature 04:  65537
Problem Signature 05:  unknown
Problem Signature 06:  OsVersionMismatch
Problem Signature 07:  0
Problem Signature 08:  0
Problem Signature 09:  unknown
OS Version: 6.0.6000.2.0.0.2561
Locale ID:             1033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that error you are using a restore disk meant for a different version of Vista and probably a different computer. I would recommend contacting the maker of your pc. You can usually order a restore disk from them for cheap.